# Increase the django-filer preview / thumbnail images within the admin

Tags: django, django-admin, thumbnails, django-filer

The images that are generated by django-filer (or easy_thumbnails?) are so little that it is hard for me to recognize the preview images. How can I increase the preview / thumbnail size in the admin overview?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to configure the size of the thumbnail displayed in the admin as of the current release (1.2.7 released 2017-03-02).

As a temporary workaround you could override the https://github.com/divio/django-filer/blob/1.2.7/filer/templates/admin/filer/folder/directory_table.html template in your project and replace all occurences of `file.icons.48` with `file.icons.64`. If you want a different size you'll also have to set the `FILER_ADMIN_ICON_SIZES` setting (it defaults to `('16', '32', '48', '64')`.

This has the downside that you'll have to check if the overridden template needs to be changed for every new release of django-filer.

A pull request that adds this functionality would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Django Filer 1.3.0 (2017-11-02):

If you change alle `file.icons.48` to `file.icons.64` it changes only the size of the loaded image.

To change the displayed size of the images you need to change https://github.com/divio/django-filer/blob/develop/filer/static/filer/css/admin_filer.css

`.filebrowser .navigator-table .column-icon{width:`**25px**`;padding-top:0 !important;padding-bottom:0 !important}`

and

`.filebrowser .navigator-table .column-icon img{width:`**25px**`;height:auto}`

to

**48px** or **64px** accordingly.